# How to bind _list_expansions in Zsh Line Editor

Tags: shell, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

I'm trying to bind "possible completions" (currently bound to `C-d`) to the key `M-=` in Zsh.

The code, therefore, should be:

```
bindkey "\e=" _list_expansions
```

but it has no effect!?  Do you understand why, and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget for the list of possible completions is called `list-choices`.

```
bindkey '\e=' list-choices
```

The widget bound on <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> by default is `list-choices` in vi mode and `delete-char-or-list` in `emacs` mode.

See `info zsh list-choices` for details.

Comment: Dunno how I found out about _list_expansions… (And, btw, I was thinking I was in Emacs mode by default, because I did not have `vi`in EDITOR nor VISUAL, but that does not seem to work, as you pointed it for the key binding to be found on C-d). Thanks a lot!